# C# Call Method in EXE

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly

I have two C# DotNet executables: PARENT.EXE and CHILD.EXE. Built with Visual Studio 2010.

I want to load and call a method in CHILD.EXE from PARENT.EXE.  So far I have been able to load CHILD.EXE as an Assembly using Assembly.LoadFrom. However, I am not clear on how to call the method in CHILD.EXE.

CHILD.EXE class looks like this:

```
namespace childnamespace;
public class childclass;
public string childmethod()
{
  return "hello world";
}
```

I want to call childmethod() from PARENT.EXE and get back the string `"hello world"`.

I see lots of articles about how to load an EXE as an assembly, but not how to actually invoke a method in that assembly.

---

Additional information: thank to @MJ's reply I have the following code in PARENT.EXE

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
public static class ConsoleTest
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Assembly SampleAssembly;
        try
        {
            SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("child.exe");
            MethodInfo Method = 
              SampleAssembly.GetType("childnamespace.childclass").GetMethod("childmethod");
            if (Method != null)
            {
                Method.Invoke(null, null);  // exception here
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

However I am getting the following exception at the indicated line:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Inner Exception:

> Value cannot be null.

Comment: Long time since the last time I used VS but can't you add a reference to CHILD in PARENT and simply use the types in the CHILD assembly?

Comment: why is child an exe and not a dll?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - it's a long story, but it needs to be this way.

Comment: @MargaretBloom - That is what I originally tried.  I added CHILD.EXE to References.CS and it did not complain. But then I tried adding the associated `using` line and it rejects everything. I tried all these: `using child`, `using childnamespace`, `using childclass` and `using childmethod` all with no luck.

Comment: `new childnamespace.childclass.childmethod()` if you add it as references ... if via LoadFrom then you have to use Reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make childmethod a static method.

```
.GetType("childnamespace.childclass").GetMethod("childmethod").Invoke(null, null);
```